# how to connect user to database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

i have create a database in mysql and also create user and granted permissions to user, please help me to connect user to database by command.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. If this is about how to grant access for an internal user to a specific database, then please refer to the documentation of the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

first you must specify the database;

```
use databasename;
```

after the username and password;